# UIDatePicker min & max height

Tags: ios, autolayout, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` in my `view` with certain constraints on it. When looking at the iPhone 5/5s and 6, it looks fine. However, on the 4s and 6+, the minimum and maximum height of the `datepicker` destroys my layout. **Is there any way of overriding these min/max values, or do you have any other suggestions for taking care of these situations?**

*Here's the constraints I have on the datepicker:*

- Align Center X to Superview
- 1:1 ratio
- Bottom Space to View Equals: 33
- Top Space to Label Equals: 5

*Here's (my guess at) what happens:*
When the `DatePicker` is placed on the screen, it tries to satisfy the *top & bottom constraints*. Then it *sets the width to match the height*. However, on the iPhone 6+, this height is too large, and it *shrinks it to a maximum height*. This creates large gaps in my design. On the 4s, it does the opposite: The height is too small, so it increases it. The `DatePicker` then overlaps my `Label`, and the space to the bottom `View` is too small. In both cases, the `DatePicker` ends up being not a square (!= 1:1).

Does anyone know if I can override these max/min values, or what I can do make sure it keeps its 1:1 ratio? And then fix the layout issues by shrinking the *33p bottom space constraint*, but not the *5p top space constraint*?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by simply wrapping the `UIDatePicker` in a separate `UIView` with the same constraints, and then setting `Clips subviews` to `YES`.

Seems to be the only way of making the `UIDatePicker` a custom size, as it has certain bounds it conforms to.